# How can we fix [stencil] vs [stencils]?

Tags: discussion, tags

[Stencil](https://github.com/stencilproject/Stencil) is a template language for Swift. I'm trying to add a tag for it to ask a question, but I get en error that there is a tag `stencils`. However, it's a completely separate technology:

[image]

Is it okay to add a tag `stencil` in this situation and if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Having "Stencil" and "stencils" both as different tags with wildly different meanings would be *super* confusing and would result in a ton of mistagging.  You'd want to create a tag that was more distinct and less ambiguous, like "stencil-language" or something along those lines.

Comment: @Servy, I like the Kendra's proposition. already done it

Comment: It doesn't look like anything more than just another Github project. Seems to be owned by a guy called Kyle Fuller, neither the project or the web page gives away any real details about him. The web page URL suggests he harks from Lichtenstein. Making it look like has anything to do with the Swift product or the Apple company might not be appropriate.

Comment: Mods can create a "stencil" tag if deemed necessary but that's the only way. Users can't create both singular and plural versions of words as tags to exist simultaneously.

Comment: And don't forget stencils used when discretizing PDEs on a grid.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_code  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_(numerical_analysis)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[stencil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stencil) and [stencils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stencils) are *incredibly similar* at first glance, and unfortunately, not everyone is going to read the tag wiki to make sure they have the right tag.

[swift-stencil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift-stencil) or, as suggested by Servy in the commments, [stencil-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stencil-language) would be better, to help differentiate the tags and hopefully prevent misuse from users who don't read the tag info.

Comment: I'd vote for swift-stencil since that keeps with existing convention.